# why composition is possible to dynamically choose a type

Tags: java, polymorphism

> A better approach is to choose composition first, especially when it’s
>   not obvious which one you should use. Composition does not force a
>   design into an inheritance hierarchy. But composition is also more
>   flexible since it’s possible to dynamically choose a type (and thus
>   behavior) when using composition, whereas inheritance requires an
>   exact type to be known at compile time. The following example
>   illustrates this

```
import static net.mindview.util.print.*;
class Actor {
  public void act() {}
}

class HappyActor extends Actor {
  public void act() {print("HappyActor"); }
}

class SadActor extends Actor {
  public void act() {print("SadActor"); }
}

class Stage {
  private Actor actor = new HappyActor();
  public void change() { actor = new SadActor(); }
  public void performPlay() {actor.act(); }
}

public class Transmogrify {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Stage stage = new Stage();
    stage.performPlay();
    stage.change();
    stage.performPlay();
  }
}
```

/*OutPut:
HappyActor
SadActor
*///:~

I was reading the book thinking in java, and i did't understand the sentence how composition dynamically choose a type ? can anybody explain to me ,thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With composition, the (dynamic) type of the actual object does not have be the (static) type of the member. It can be any subclass of that type.

E.g. in your example, the member `actor` can point to any object in the inheritance tree of `Actor`. So `actor` can also point to a `HappyActor` or `SadActor`, too. Thus, you can have a different dynamic type at runtime.

With Inheritance, the actual type would be fixed:

```
class Actor {
  public void act() {}
}

class HappyActor extends Actor {
  public void act() {print("HappyActor"); }
}

class Stage extends HappyActor {
  public void change() { /* Cannot change dynamic type */ }
  public void performPlay() {this.act(); } // call inherited act method
}
```

This will always output `HappyActor`

Comment: And using composition you could then, for example, change which type of actor was performing based on a configuration file, or something else that happens in the system (or play, to stick with the domain language)

Comment: How could `Stage` ever extend `HappyActor`?

Comment: The question was about how composition can provide dynamic typing, as opposed to inheritance. This is just an example how the other way would look like, using the provided classes

Comment: Thanks for answer, You are right. Now, I understand what the author wants to express

Answer (score 2):

It's perhaps poorly worded.  It's not about type but behavior.  Behavior can dynamically change at runtime when you favor composition over inheritance -- and it works better when you match it with an interface which doesn't constrain your type hierarchy.

consider the standard:

```
interface Painter {
    public String getName();
    public void paint( Canvas c );
}

class Canvas {
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "a canvas.";
    }
}

class NouveauPainter implements Painter {
    public void paint( Canvas c ) {
        System.out.printf "%s Painted a nouveau stroke on %s.\n", 
            getName(),
            c );
    }
public String getName() {
    return getClass().getSimpleName();
}

}

class ClassicPainter implements Painter {
    public void paint( Painter p, Canvas c ) {
        System.out.printf "%s Painted a classic stroke on %s.\n", 
            getName(),
            c );
    }
public String getName() {
    return getClass().getSimpleName();
}

}

public class DoSomePainting() {
    public static void main( String...args ) {
        Canvas c = new Canvas();
        Painter oldschool = new ClassicPainter();
        oldschool.paint(c);

        Painter newschool = new NouveauPainter();
        oldschool.paint(c);
    }
}
```

You have to choose one type of painter or the other.  But what if you want to be able to change the stroke at runtime?  This is often necessary.  If the paint method were embedded in a parent class ( or abstract class ) you'd be stuck to the type hierarchy if you wanted to re-use functionality and might end up with all kinds of leaky abstractions and god classes.  consider the follwing:

```
interface Stroke {
    public void paint( Painter p, Canvas c )
}

class ClassicStroke {
    public void paint( Painter p, Canvas c ) {
        System.out.printf "%s Painted a classic stroke on %s.\n", 
            p.getName(),
            c );
    }
}

class NouveauStroke {
    public void paint() {
        System.out.printf "%s Painted a nouveau stroke on %s.\n", 
            p.getName(),
            c );
    }
}


class GenericPainter implements Painter {

    public Stroke stroke = null;

    public void paint( Canvas c ) {
        stroke.paint( this, c );
    }

public String getName() {
    return getClass().getSimpleName();
}


}

public class DoSomePainting() {
    public static void main( String...args ) {
        Canvas c = new Canvas();
        Painter versatile = new GenericPainter();

        versatile.stroke = new ClassicStroke();
        versatile.paint(c);
        versatile.stroke = new NouveauStroke();
        versatile.paint(c);

    }
}
```

Now the definition of a painter, and the implementation of it's parts, are clearly separated and can be re-used just about anywhere.

NOTE:  I'm not sure if this all compiles -- it's more for illustrative purposes and coding in a text box is awkward.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, An interface actually works better,It dostn't need type hierachy

Comment: -shrug-  composition is more about what happens after the interface.  Often there's some default implementation details that end up in some sort of a common ancestor class and that's when thing start to go in strange directions.

Most often the pattern comes in two or thee pieces.  A helper/support class which implements the default functionality and takes an internal interface to tie it to the class being composed, the internal interface, and the external interface.

What I mean is, the ideas are complimentary, not conflicting.